# rewind causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I've been trying to do some debugging when my program came up with a segmentation fault. I've tracked it down to where rewind is called.

The file is opened when an ISBNPrefix object is created

```
ISBNPrefix::ISBNPrefix(const char* filename) 
{

   file = fopen( filename, "r" );

}
```

file is a member of the ISBNPrefix class:

```
class ISBNPrefix {
FILE* file;
public:
    ISBNPrefix(const char* filename);
    bool isRegistered(int area) const;
    int minNoDigits(int area) const;
    bool isRegistered(int area, const char* publisher) const;
    ~ISBNPrefix();
};
```

The line that creates the ISBNPrefix object is:

```
ISBNPrefix prefixList("prefixRanges.txt");
```

prefixRanges.txt is the name of the file in my directory

Right now I have the segmentation fault occuring at this section:

```
//-------------------------------
cout << "MADE IT 1" << endl;
//-------------------------------
   rewind( file );
//-------------------------------
cout << "MADE IT 2" << endl;
//-------------------------------
```

Which outputs:

```
MADE IT 1
Segmentation fault
```

The deconstructor:

```
ISBNPrefix::~ISBNPrefix()
{
   if( file != NULL )
   {
      fclose(file);
   }
}
```

Is the only place that the file is closed

Edit: After some troubleshooting, a solution wasn't found and it was suggested that I post everything. Since my reputation is low and I can't post more than 2 links, the pastebin links are in the comments section.

Comment: Add `<< endl` after both the null checks...it's possible the buffer isn't flushed.

Comment: I'm not seeing a copy constructor or an assignment operator in your `ISBNPrefix` class but I am seeing a destructor. That would be my first guess as to the problem. In particular if your destructor closes the file then you have a problem, and that possibly explains the segfault you are seeing.

Comment: Please share more "application" code i.e. the code which instantiates your ISBN.. objects

Comment: Post your `rewind` code if possible, as well.

Comment: @Tushar `rewind` is a standard C function (or macro maybe).

Comment: @john I see, thanks. `down to my rewind function` threw me off :)

Comment: @Tushar sorry about that, made it more clear

Comment: @user2177874 Everything is pointing to it being a copy constructor/assignment operator/destructor problem. Do you close the file in the destructor? If so then put `cout << "CLOSED FILE\n";` in the destructor and see whether the file is closed before you think it should have been.

Comment: @john I put `cout << "CLOSED FILE\n"` in the deconstructor, right after `fclose(file);` but the output doesn't change

Comment: @user2177874. OK well then that's a problem for the future. Your problem right now is something else. Not enough information to tell unfortunately.

Comment: @john what can I add to help?

Comment: The whole program? The problem with code is that the place it crashes is very rarely the place that the bug is. So complete programs are what's needed if you want more than educated guesses.

Comment: @john 
ISBN.cpp
[link](http://pastebin.com/4idGmcAZ)

ISBN.h
[link](http://pastebin.com/GS1FCfja)

ISBNPrefix.cpp
[link](http://pastebin.com/S6aPVRHz)

ISBNPrefix.h
[link](http://pastebin.com/BFmuZaNK)

Comment: @user2177874 I don't see `main`. Also I'm not sure about the file format. Are you remembering to account for the null terminator in a C style string? I can see a few issues however. Of course they may not be related to the problem you are seeing, but your code in `ISBN::toStr` and `ISBN::toStrWithStyle` is bugged. You cannot append C strings with `+=`, you need `strcat` for that.

Comment: @john Sorry, here is the main [link](http://pastebin.com/ZBRNRB6r)

`strcat` wasn't working when I was trying to add a single char to the end. I looked online and found a piece of advice that said `+=` was worked, but wasn't as efficient as could be

Comment: How about the file prefixRanges.txt? Need to see what you're actually reading.

Comment: @john prefixRanges.txt [link](http://pastebin.com/iZEHBX7Z)

Comment: @user2177874 - if your problem is solved please accept the answer, there is no need to edit title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the problem you see, but I do see a serious problem. On my system it causes your program to crash on exit. Maybe on your system it's the cause of your problem.

This code in the ISBN header

```
class ISBN{
        char area[5];
        char publisher[7];
        char title[6];
        bool registered;
        char ISBNstr[11];
        bool isRegistered(const ISBNPrefix& list);
```

and this code in the ISBN constructor

```
ISBN::ISBN()
{
   for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
   {
   area[i] = '\0';
   }

   for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
   {
   publisher[i] = '\0';
   }

   for(int i=0;i<=6;i++)
   {
   title[i] = '\0';
   }

   for(int i=0;i<=11;i++)
   {
   ISBNstr[i] = '\0';
   }
   registered = false;
}
```

Those loops all go round one too many times. E.g. it should be `i<5` not `i<=5` in the area loop

```
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
   area[i] = '\0';
   }
```

Because of this bug you are corrupting memory and that could easily cause the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Okay, I think that fixed it, I've got other problems, but it's at least not giving segfaults, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
if(file != NULL)
cout << "ITS NOT NULL";
   rewind( file );
```

should have been

```
if(file != NULL)
{
    cout << "ITS NOT NULL";
    rewind( file );
}
```

In the first version, only the ourput statement was conditional, no matter how much you indented the following line...

I suppose it is a good practice to always include brackets ({}) even for single statement blocks, to avoid simple stuff like this. Also, format your code properly, and make sure the indentation follows the actual code structure. E.g.:

```
if(file != NULL)
    cout << "ITS NOT NULL";
rewind( file );  // it would have been more obvious this way
```

Comment: That didn't help, the output is still giving a Segmentation fault

Comment: hmmm I don't think this can solve his issue as `ITS NOT NULL` is printed

Comment: I think you're on the wrong track. The code is just for debugging. The expectation is that file will not be NULL. My guess is that file has been closed but the OP doesn't realise it.

Comment: Mmm. you have good points, still, that code was a bit broken IMO.