# rewind causes segmentation fault in c++

Tags: c++

I have serious problem which is segmentation fault and i am %99.99 sure its because of rewind.
   i have somewhat big loop and it runs about 1200 time. in each run of my loop i rewind(fp) in 2 different class method. in visual studio it goes up to 527 times and then when i look at the value of fp, it says unable to read memory. i copy the same code to matrix environment and it goes up to 1027 test.if i stop rewinding i dont get error but my result will be wrong.
   now my question:
   when each time i rewind, is anyway to delete it from memory at the end of my loop?

for example

```
FILE* fp;
fp=fopen("filename","r");
for(..;..;..)
{
rewind(fp);

 //beginning of my code
 .
 .
 .

 //end of my code
is there any command i can use to clear fp from memory right here?
}
```

any comment makes me grateful

Comment: A similar question was posted before which might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454132/rewind-causes-segmentation-fault

Comment: Did you check if the fine is actually opened, `fp` was NULL or not?

Comment: Since I'm fairly sure a bug in `rewind()` would have caused havoc in other software too, I suspect that your loop is accidentally overwriting memory somewhere. Sadly, it's all but impossible to guess where that "somewhere" is though without seeing more of the actual code.

Comment: Provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), please.

Comment: I agree with Joachim's assessment, but if you're concerned it might be `rewind()`, just `fclose` and re-`fopen` the file instead. If that happens to work, it's probably a coincidence though. It seems more likely to me that when you don't rewind your process just doesn't see enough input to fail. Another way to test that might be to concatenate several (potentially partial) copies of the file and use that for input without rewinding, such that the processing is the same....